# $.ajax json method does not hit the web method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, ajax

When this function is hit , it does not call my function in code behind? Why could it be doing this? How can I fix this error.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
           $('[id$=btn_Update]').click(function() { 

           var reten = $('[id$=txt_Reten]').val();
            var i=0; 
            var selectValues = "";
            var ProdID = new Array();         
            $("#lst_ProdId option").each(function() {  
                 selectValues = selectValues + $(this).text() + ",";                 
                 ProdID[i] = $(this).text();
                 i++;

             });  
             for(var j=0; j < ProdID.length;j++)
             {
               // alert(ProdID[j]);
             }

          var params = "{'ProdID':'" + ProdID + "','RetenP':'" + reten + "'}";
             $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/ProductPricing/Products/RetenPeriod.aspx/UpdateRetenPeriod",
                    data: params,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                    
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function(result) {
                        alert("sucess");
                    },
                    error:function(e) {
                        alert(e.statusText);
//                        if(errorThrown != null)
//                            alert(textStatus+ ":"+errorThrown);
//                        else
//                            alert("fail");
                    }
                    });             
             return false;
             });
             return false;
        });
```

This is my webmethod in code behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool UpdateRetenPeriod(string[] ProdID,string RetenP)  
{
     for (int i = 0; i < ProdID.Length; i++)
     {
        update(ProdID[i],RetenP);
      }

    return true;

}
```

Comment: Use Firebug and look at the request and response. What do you see?

Comment: If you do you development in VS, you can place a breakpoint in your WebMethod, to see it is actually called or not. I'm not sure at all, is it even possible to call static method of aspx page like that (I could be wrong).

Answer (score 1):

Does it call the `error` method?

You need to return JSON. Not a boolean. Perhaps something like `{success: true}`.

Then:

```
success: function(data) {
   if(data.success) {
       ...
   }

   else {
      ...
   }
}
```

jQuery expects JSON and will throw an error if it doesn't receive well-formed JSON. Also, what is the exact response you're getting back? You can use something like Firebug to figure this out.

One more thing. Can you verify that you can successfully hit that URL? Are you able to successfully point your browser to `http://your.url.here/ProductPricing/Products/RetenPeriod.aspx/UpdateRetenPeriod`?

Also look at Pointy's solution. Your request is unlikely to succeed since you aren't passing in an actual object literal.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing your parameters as a string instead of as an object literal:

```
 var params = "{'ProdID':'" + ProdID + "','RetenP':'" + reten + "'}";
```

should (almost certainly) be:

```
 var params = {'ProdID': ProdID,'RetenP': reten};
```

Also, how do you *know* that the ajax request is not making it to the server? Have you tried tracing the HTTP requests with something like TamperData (for Firefox) or Firebug (also Firefox)?

Comment: I'm not an ASP developer, so for all I know something in the server framework might un-hack strings like that :-)

Comment: Neither am I :) Maybe it is able to parse something like that

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a ScriptManager defined in the markup with EnablePageMethods set to true?

Also, I believe your params line should be:

```
var params = "{ProdID:'" + ProdID + "', RetenP:'" + reten + "'}";
```

I have several functions in my own apps that do it this way.  You want the value of params to look like this: "{ProdID:'1,2', RetenP:'undefined'}"

Can you place a breakpoint at alert(e.statusText); to see what the error message is?

Comment: Why would you do it this way when you can use an object literal?

Comment: I'm honestly not a javascript developer so I wasn't aware the object literal method would work. When I do use the object literal, though, I get "Invalid JSON primitive: ProdID"

Comment: That's odd. jQuery should serialize it without a problem. Strange!

Answer (score 0):

Have u got error message.. please, try to get the error message

I think, u can use this by replacing error block

```
error:
   function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
         alert( "Error Occured!" + errorThrown.toString());
   }
```

I think, problems occurred in code behind method.. if in [web method] has any problem, then ajax doesn't call the method..